# Is it possible to create custom transition for pages in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, animation

I want to do custom transition between pages while swiping  in UIPageViewController like 3Dcubic transition.

How Do I do?

Only way do this is
When swiping current page make the next page view 3d transform?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I did a google search for `custom transition between pages while swiping in UIPageViewController` and found lots of results / tutorials / examples / etc.

Comment: They don’t show it  for pagecontroller. Only for custom viewcontrollers.

Comment: Can you ahow a link?

Comment: See this answer - looks similar to what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25837848/6257435

Comment: Thank you. One last question, instagram stories (in 3d cubic) are in collectionview or uiviewpagecontroller?

Comment: Sorry - couldn't tell you. I don't use Instagram.

Answer (score 2):

With `UIPageViewController` you can only pick between scroll and page curl transitioning.

To implement custom transitions you'll need to build on a more abstract/flexible controller, like `UICollectionViewController`.