# How to add fade-in fade-out animation for uipageviewcontroller in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

`UIPageViewController` scroll and page-curl animation are there, but I need to add a fade-out/fade-in animation on scrolling time.

How can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController: Fade In/Out Animation Between Viewcontrollers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837433/uipageviewcontroller-fade-in-out-animation-between-viewcontrollers)

Comment: UIPageViewController  Slideing Animation in ios swift

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the link @SchrgCat posted before. Look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25837848/5464805, try to set it up and if it still doesnt work, past your code of what you tried so far.

Comment: uipageviewcontroller haveing two transmission styles like scroll and page-curl  but i want add  custom style in ios siwft.

Comment: Is it possible to use custom transition style for PageViewController rather than using Page Curl or Scroll transitions?

Comment: how could imitate UIPageViewcontroller by yourself and add my own transition, my example transition example code, please help me, anyone?